# assertTrue() doesn't enter inner function paramter

Tags: java, debugging, trie

So I made a Trie class with these variables.

```
Node rootNode = new Node();
int nodeCount = 1;
int wordCount = 0;
static StringBuilder indexList1 = new StringBuilder();
static StringBuilder indexList2 = new StringBuilder();
```

I am currently trying to build an equals function for the trie and the way I am doing that is buy traversing through the trie and concatenating indexes into a static string builder. When that is done for both objects, I compare the strings. Here is the code for the equals function:

```
public void equalsHelper(Node n1, int List) {
    if (List == 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
            if(n1.nodes[i] != null) {
                indexList1.append(i);
                indexList1.append(n1.nodes[i].frequency);
                equalsHelper(n1.nodes[i], List);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (List == 2) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
            if(n1.nodes[i] != null) {
                indexList2.append(i);
                indexList2.append(n1.nodes[i].frequency);
                equalsHelper(n1.nodes[i], List);
            }
        }
    }
}

public boolean equals(Trie trie2) {
    System.out.println("I was entered");
    if (this.nodeCount == 1 && trie2.nodeCount == 1) return true;
    if (indexList1.length() > 0) indexList1.setLength(0);
    if (indexList2.length() > 0) indexList2.setLength(0);
    if (this.wordCount != trie2.wordCount || this.nodeCount != trie2.nodeCount) return false;
    equalsHelper(this.rootNode, 1);
    equalsHelper(trie2.rootNode, 2);
    return indexList1.toString() == indexList2.toString();
}
```

So here is the problem, when I run it through this test case, it doesn't even seem to enter the function **equals**

```
add("cares");
add("caress");
add("baboon");
studentTrie.add("car");         
studentTrie2.add("car");
assertTrue(studentTrie.equals(studentTrie2), "Equal Trie objects found unequal");
```

All that it does is immediately return false. When I try to step through the debugger, it doesn't even seem to enter the equals call but somehow returns false when it should be returning true. This is the error it shows me.

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Equal Trie objects found unequal ==> expected: <true> but was: <false>

at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.fail(AssertionUtils.java:40)
at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertTrue.assertTrue(AssertTrue.java:42)
at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue(Assertions.java:160)
at passoff.TrieTest.testEquals(TrieTest.java:93)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:513)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:170)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:40)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:166)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:113)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:58)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:113)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:121)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:121)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:121)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:121)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:55)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:43)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:170)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:154)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:90)
at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
```

I am wondering if there is something I just don't know about the assertFalse/assertTrue functions. Anyways, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `expected: <true> but was: <false>` what is the problem?

Comment: sorry the problem is that it should be true

Comment: Note that you should override the `equals` method in order to make it work as you expect it to work.

Comment: That is a good thought but for when I do that it says "Method does not override method from its superclass"

Comment: *it doesn't even seem to enter the function equals* sure it does. It even returns a value - `false`

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you are using different `equals` method (if you are 10000 % sure implementation is fine)

Comment: You shouldn't have `@Override` because you're not overriding it, you're overloading it, since it has a different signature (Object other vs Trie other).

Does it enter the original equals method? You can put a breakpoint in the `Object` class.

Comment: Another thing is that why `equals` is mutating its subjects is a mistery to me.

Comment: So it is going into the Object equals! This is great to know. How would I make it go into the correct equals function?

Comment: How are you declaring the Trie variables? If your equals method is in the Trie class, and both instances are Trie, then it should use that method.

Comment: They are just declared like this             studentTrie = new spell.Trie();
            studentTrie2 = new spell.Trie();

Comment: why `List` is an `int` ..... `(Node n1, int List) {` ....

Comment: It is just telling which list to work on. :D I could make it a better variable name.

Answer (score 1):

Strings are supposed to be compared with `String#equals` not `==`

```
return indexList1.toString() == indexList2.toString();
```

Comment: That is a good point! It doesn't solve the problem but thanks! I just started learning Java this semester. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was that once I found the function wasn't going into the correct class, I realized that I never overrode the function. I found this page helpful! https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overriding-equals-method-in-java/

I just needed to do that and it worked out great! I am very grateful for all the different suggestions that got me on the right track.